# How can I programatically measure the vagueness of text?

Tags: algorithm, text, nlp

I want to provide a service that finds job postings on other sites and lets users painlessly apply for those jobs.

What I would like to provide is a form of automated screening for postings; specifically, I'd like to add an option to filter out postings with vague language in case a user doesn't want job postings from 3rd party recruiters(since vague language is a tell-tale sign of those kind of postings).

Is there an algorithm which I can use to measure the vagueness or clarity-level of some text?

Comment: I've removed the request of an API/library recommendation: they are off topic here and people were voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you need a classifier for job descriptions into 2 classes: "3rd parties" and "employers themselves". It is a classic [text classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification) task, very similar to [spam filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_filtering).

Main differences from spam filtering are the following:

1. Vague boundary between classes: even human can't often determine the source of job description.
2. Almost no counteraction from authors of job descriptions.

So, I recommend to use supervised machine learning approach for your task. Create train set of job descriptions - it is not so hard to collect 100-200 of each type, and that would be enough, I guess. Then try ML classifiers like Random forest, Logistic regression or Naive Bayes with simple features like bag-of-words; name of the person who uploaded job description; length of the text; also try some binary features, e.g. presence of special words like the ones recommended by @Sklivvz♦.

Look at [Naive Bayes spam filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering) for example.

Your classes ("vague text" and  "clear text") seem to be too vague for creating effective classifier. In addition, your assumption that this classification is equivalent to the classification I formulated above (and that is you really needed in), doesn't look like a reliable one.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote something similar, even though not exactly what you ask, on my website for Careers Stack Overflow.

There are some phrases which commonly indicate a vague job ad: corporate jargon words. While it's pretty hard to determine whether a single word or phrase is *actually* used in a jargon-y way, it becomes quite evident that many bad postings have many matches - they use many such words.

You can test the [tool](http://sklivvz.com/jargon) here and there's more [explanations](http://sklivvz.com/posts/make-your-job-ads-23-better-with-these-5-weird-tricks) on the site.

Regarding the code, it's simply a series of static compiled regexes. Simple and works for my needs.

```
void Main()
{

    string test = "developer-centric vision of insourcing";
    var matches = BadChecks.SelectMany(bad => 
        bad.Matches(test)
           .Cast<Match>()
           .Select(m => m.Value.ToLowerInvariant())
        ).ToList();

    foreach (var res in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(res);

}

private static readonly List<Regex> BadChecks = SetupBadChecks();

private static List < Regex > SetupBadChecks() {
    return new List < string > {
        "(#1|number (one|1))",
        "([a-z]+)-free",
        "(Out|in)sourcing",
        "-centric",
        "a wider net",
        "Aggregator",
        "Alignment",
        "all hands on deck",
        //  more
        "Wellness",
        "Win(-| )win",
        "World(-| )class"
    }.Select(s => new Regex(s, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |
                               RegexOptions.CultureInvariant |
                               RegexOptions.Compiled))
     .ToList();
}
```

Which returns

> insourcing
>   -centric